# Painting fences, probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $a$ yellow and $b$ green fences, and on each day one of these fences is getting painted green, choosen at uniform probability, meaning $\dfrac{a}{a+b}$ yellow and $\dfrac{b}{a+b}$ for green, even though it might already be green. How can I calculate the probability, that after $a+1$ days all fences are green? I know that there are $(a + b)^{a+ 1}$ ways one could paint them, but I can't figure out how to count the events that result in all fences being green.

Comment: Note that the probability changes every time a yellow fence gets painted green.

Comment: Can the same fence get painted more than once...or after a fence has been painted is it out of the running to get painted again?

Comment: @paw88789 thanks, but I've been struggling for a long time for this problem, and even though I know that I probably won't get a full solution here, I would still be very glad if someone could point out the steps to solve this (I'm very new to probability)

Comment: @paw88789 a fence can get painted arbitrary often, meaning there is also the case that only one fence gets painted at all days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We must paint all the $a$ yellow fences green within the interval of $a + 1$ days, so we are only allowed to paint the wrong fence once (one that was already green). The probability that we make no mistakes at all is equal to $p_0 = \prod_{0 \leq k \leq a - 1} \frac{a - k}{a + b} = \frac{a!}{(a + b)^a}.$ The probability that we make the mistake on day $j$ is $p_j = \frac{b + j - 1}{a + b} p_0$ (up until day $j$ we would have painted $j - 1$ fences green, so we have $b + j - 1$ choices; the number $p_0$ still appears because we compute the probability of painting only yellow fences up until day $j$ and we get the first $j - 1$ terms in $p_0$ and from day $j + 1$ to day $a + 1$ we get the rest of the terms). Therefore, the total probability is equal to $$\sum_{0 \leq j \leq a} p_j = p_0 + \frac{p_0}{a+b} \sum_{1 \leq j \leq a} b + j - 1 = p_0 + \frac{p_0}{a + b}(ab + \frac{a(a - 1)}{2}).$$ Note that $p_{a + 1}$ does not appear in the sum because this is actually $p_0.$ I hope this helps. :)

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick answer!